# Getting Position of Marker After Dragging Laravel-VUE based component

Tags: laravel, google-maps, vue.js

I am using
[vue-google-maps](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-google-maps/)

They working good so far, I want to achieve that when someone search and select their area a marker appears and then they can drag it to their required position.

I have so far managed to make the marker draggable by editing GoogleMap.vue file

```
<gmap-marker 
    :key="index"

    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :draggable="true"
    @click="center=m.position"
    @drag="setCurrent(this)"

  ></gmap-marker>
```

Now I am able to drag the marker however the coordinates (lat:long) doesn't change.

I am using Laravel 1.4.1
Vue 3.0.0-beta.6

Please help

rest of the GoogleMap.vue look like this

```
<script>
   export default {
   name: "GoogleMap",
   data() {
    return {

      center: { lat: 24.9004057, lng: 67.1926178 },
      markers: [],
      places: [],
      currentPlace: null,

     };
    },

   mounted() {

 this.geolocate();

},

   methods: {

    // receives a place object via the autocomplete component
    setPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
      this.addMarker();
    },

addMarker() {

  if (this.currentPlace) {
    const marker = {
      lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
      lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng()
    };
    this.markers.push({ position: marker, draggable: true });
    this.places.push(this.currentPlace);
    this.center = marker;
    this.currentPlace = null;
  }
},

geolocate: function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    this.center = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
  });
},

checkthis(position){

  console.log(navigator.position.getCurrentPosition());

 }

} 

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get marker position once it is dragged [`Marker.dragend`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.dragend) is better suited then [`Marker.drag`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.drag):

> This event is fired when the user stops dragging the marker.

In case of [vue-google-maps](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-google-maps/) library marker position could be determined like this:

```
<gmap-marker
    :draggable="true"
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    @click="center=m.position"
    @dragend="showLocation"
  ></gmap-marker>


showLocation: function(evt){
     console.log( evt.latLng.toString());
}
```

where `evt` is a [`MouseEvent` object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and `MouseEvent.latLng` property contains the position of dragged marker

The same applies to `@drag` event.